# What do you call these plastic that wraps around books/magazines?

Tags: single-word-requests

They look like this:

[image][image]

Do you usually just call them plastic wrappers or wrappings?

Comment: I would call it a *sleeve* until it introduced itself properly.

Comment: I'm certain there's a technical term in publishing, but the general public will likely not refer to the plastic as *X*, but rather to the magazines/comics as *sealed*.

Comment: I would call it a *cellophane bag* because cellophane is a thin, transparent sheet made of regenerated cellulose.

Comment: The bags shown look like [polyethylene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene) rather than [cellulose](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cellulose) or [Cellophane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellophane), ie probably are [poly bags](https://www.google.com/search?q=poly+bags&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Fhk_UoehOoGbiAK_-oDwCA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1016&bih=604&dpr=1.5)

Comment: At our publishing company, as jwpat7 mentions, we call these *polybags*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the article is tight-wrapped in that material, or with some people any material, people use the adjective "**shrink-wrapped**" or "shrink-wrapped in cellophane". When it's wrapped loose—and often fastened with a bow—, as with holiday presents, people usually say "in cellophane bag" or "in cellophane."

Edit: AFAIK and concerning mostly AE

Comment: Unless you're a Brit, where we just say 'plastic wrapper or plastic wrap'.

Comment: I don't think this fully or perhaps even effectivey answers the question. Shrink-wrapped refers to a means of (tightly) covering the book/magazine. But, especially as magazines are concerned, I don't think the term Shrink-wrapped is the whole story; comments to the original question seem to support this statement.